# A body is rotated in air and is dropped on the floor slowly

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

When a body is rotated with a constant angular velocity $\omega$ and is dropped to ground, the friction should act as in the picture below[image]

Now, because of the friction, the center of mass must accelerate forward and the body should continue moving forward until the friction stops acting when the velocity of the point of contact is 0. Hence the body should continue moving forward till infinity

But when I try this experiment with a pen, the pen stops after some time which seems to contradict what I think should happen. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it first hits the ground, if it is rotating  fast enough to exceed the co efficient of static friction, it will have kinetic friction while it is slipping. This will start it accelerating forward until it stops slipping. Then it will have rolling (static) friction with the ground. It will also have friction from air resistance. These frictions will act to slow its rotation until it eventually stops.

Comment: What is the basis of the assumption that it will have kinetic friction when it first hits the ground. Why can't it be static friction?

Comment: @BobD Would instant maximum horizontal speed be reached with no slipping?

Comment: Why can't it? As long as the maximum possible static friction force is not exceeded.

Comment: @BobD I respect your knowledge so I have made an edit. I suppose in some cases material  deformation could maintain static friction from the moment of contact. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @BobD Having static friction from the moment of contact would imply that the pen's horizontal velocity goes from zero to some non-zero value *instantaneously*. In order for there to be no slipping, the pen's horizontal motion must match its rotational motion. If there really is no slipping, that indicates that the horizontal motion takes on that match speed at the moment of contact, implying infinite acceleration and frictional force.

Comment: @NuclearWang Good points.

Comment: @AdrianHoward , I know this is a bit late but the static friction should produce a clockwise torque which increases the angular velocity while decreasing the velocity of centre of mass.But we dont see an increase in angular velocity while doing the experiment

Comment: @Get_RiGhT  Static friction decreases angular velocity and decreases the velocity of the COM

Comment: @AdrianHoward Both of those cant happen at the same time cause if the static friction is acting to the left, it will produce a torque which increases angular velocity

Comment: @Get_RiGhT Both must happen, friction force to the left acts against the cylinders inertial momentum to the right and it slows.

Answer (score 2):

There are two factors you haven't considered:

1. If the surface is not perfectly flat, bumps and ridges and other stuff (dirt, etc) will have non-horizontal interactions with the cylinder, exerting torque on the cylinder about the rotational axis opposite the angular velocity. While similar to air resistance (collisions with molecules), I believe this will be a much larger effect.  Try rolling a rod across carpet (lots of bumps and ridges) versus a linoleum or flat vinyl floor.
2. If the surface is not perfectly level, gravity will cause torque which could stop (or speed up) the angular motion.

Comment: Also air resistance.